# How to restrict lambda parameter's parameter to only be a reference?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying to design a simple function like this:

```cpp
void draw(Callback callback)
{
    Drawing drawing("name");
    callback(drawing);

    std::cout << drawing.name() << std::endl;
}
```

where `drawing` should be passed to the callback as a reference, so that the caller can modify it like so:

```cpp
draw([](auto& drawing) {
    drawing.set_name("another name");
});
```

Now this works, because I'm explicitly typing the callback parameter as `auto&` (or `Drawing&`).
However, when I just type the parameter as `auto` (or `Drawing`), the code also compiles but no longer works as expected. The `drawing` instance is copied rather than passed by reference.

I'd like the code to no longer compile when the lambda parameter is not explicitly typed as a reference.

I've tried the following:

- `using Callback = std::function<void(Drawing&)>;`: `drawing` is not modified when not explicitly typing as `auto&`.
- `template<typename T> concept Callback = std::is_invocable<void, T, Drawing&>;`: same as above.
- `using Callback = void (*)(Drawing&);`: this actually works, but I loose the ability to use capture.

So how do I go about properly typing Callback so that only `Drawing&` is a valid parameter to the lambda?

Comment: As a side note, I've seemingly also answered my own question: "The drawing instance is copied". If I just delete the copy constructor/assignment operator, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could constrain `draw` so that it cannot be called with an rvalue-accepting `callback`:

```cpp
template <typename Callback>
  requires (std::invocable<Callback, Drawing&> && !std::invocable<Callback, Drawing&&>)
void draw(Callback callback)
{
    Drawing drawing("name");
    callback(drawing);

    std::cout << drawing.name() << std::endl;
}
```

If the given `callback` accepted `auto` or `auto&&`, it would not satisfy the constraint:

```cpp
int main() {
    draw([](auto& drawing) {}); // OK
    draw([](auto drawing) {});  // error: no matching function call ...
}
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/cz3Yeab4j).*

#### Why this works

The only kind of reference that cannot bind to rvalues is a non-const lvalue reference.
By constraining the function so that the callback cannot accept an rvalue, we disqualify callbacks that take `Drawing`, `Drawing&&`, `const Drawing&`, and `const Drawing&&`, since all of these can bind to an rvalue.

Essentially, we force the user to take `Drawing&` (or `auto&`), and accidental copying is impossible because lvalue references cannot bind to temporary objects.

*Note: rvalue references are converted to xvalues of the same type prior to any analysis; that's why I'm saying "rvalues" and not talking about references in these bullets.*

#### Further advice

Note that if your goal is that `Drawing` isn't accidentally copied, you can more reliably prevent this by explicitly deleting its copy constructor and copy assignment operator.
However, that would obviously apply everywhere, not just within `draw`.

Comment: How does preventing `Callback` from accepting an rvalue reference prevent `drawing` from being passed by value?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've added some extra explanation on this. Is it clear now?

Comment: Not really, since the `drawing` object inside of `draw()` is an lvalue, not an rvalue, and passing it by value does not make it an rvalue. So how does preventing rvalue references also prevent pass-by-value?

Comment: @RemyLebeau because if your callback supports pass-by-value, it also supports passing rvalues. If you ensure it doesn't support rvlaues, there can't be pass-by-value.